# SRS Reports: URL Parameters, Multiple Values

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

Similar to this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078863/passing-parameter-via-url-to-sql-server-reporting-service)

However I have already mastered that. My problem is a new report we just added at work has values for parameters (i.e.:10-New, 20-Cancel, 30-Complete). For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to pass multiple values for the same parameter. (so from the previous example, choosing 10-New and 30-Complete as values for the parameter).

Can this be done? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you do it the same way as any other report, you just comma separate your list (i.e. 10,20), which is why you need a function to split your comma separated string into a table for your where clause (sounds like you've already got this covered)

Comment: wait, what? The SQL Report Service server has a report viewer URL (see that other post if you are not sure what I am talking about), it automatically parses parameters with a built in routine to display the report. I have no control over that. I have tried a comma, and it does not accept that.

Comment: If you've got your SQL stored in the report, you don't have to worry about that. If you've got it in a Stored Procedure, then SSRS passes in the multi-value parameter in as a comma delimited string, which you then have to parse out or convert into a table. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337396%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: that is odd, still does not work, but that was the article I was not able to track down. I will forward this back to our report team. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing mutiple values to a paremeter, first make sure the parameter is marked to allow multiple values.

Then in your query make sure you use some sort of split function to separate out the string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to split it.  You can do the following...
Ensure that the first, and last values in the comma-delim string are enclosed by quotes (I use a udf to do this)

```
IF CHARINDEX(',', @Param) <> 1 SET @Value = ',' + @Value        
IF CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@Value)) <> 1 SET @Value = @Value + ','
```

Then, enclose your field that will be filtered in commas and wild-card expression and use a LIKE comparison to filter your clause...

```
SELECT
    t.Field1,
    t.Field2
FROM
    dbo.Table1 t
WHERE
    '%,' + t.Field + ',%' LIKE @Parm
```

Works like a dream on any string fields, but can get tricky with dates and integers, etc.
You will then have to also CAST the field you are filtering to a VARCHAR.