# how do i pass page group value to different datasets in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have 2 datasets in ssrs. one is with union and other one is simple query,but i have to pass parameter to both datasets without entering by user, instead use page paramenter which is equipment number.basically report is displaying based on each equipment number and which should pass to these datasets. 
one dataset query  is

```
SELECT        
    BHEQNO
    ,CertifDesc
    ,Company
    ,EffDate
    ,ExpDate
    ,BHEQSN
    ,BHEQIV
    ,BHEQYR
    ,BHEQMF
    ,0 AS AI
    ,0 AS LP
    ,CZDRNM
    ,CZADD1
    ,CZCITY
    ,CZST
    ,CZZIP
    ,BHEQNO AS Equip
    ,NULL AS Name
    ,NULL AS Addess
    ,NULL AS City
    ,NULL AS State
    ,NULL AS Zip
    ,Rate
    ,ShortName
    ,ExportShortName
    ,Coverage
FROM            
    EquipmentRateLookUp
WHERE        
    BHEQNO = @BHEQNO
UNION ALL
SELECT        
    EquipmentNumber
    ,NULL AS Expr6
    ,NULL AS Expr7
    ,NULL AS Expr8
    ,NULL AS Expr9
    ,NULL AS Expr10
    ,NULL AS Expr11
    ,NULL AS Expr12
    ,NULL AS Expr13
    ,AI
    ,LP
    ,NULL AS Expr14
    ,NULL AS Expr15
    ,NULL AS Expr16
    ,NULL AS Expr17
    ,NULL AS Expr18
    ,NULL AS Expr19
    ,Name
    ,Address
    ,City
    ,State
    ,ZIP
    ,0 As Rate
    ,NULL As ShortName
    ,NULL As EShortName
    ,NULL As Coverage
FROM            
    LossPayee
WHERE        
    EquipmentNumber = @BHEQNO
```

**Second dataset**

```
SELECT        
    EquipmentNumber
    ,EBDRNO
    ,EBEFDTF
    ,EBEFDTT
    ,EBTXID
    ,EBNAME1
    ,EBADD1
    ,EBADD2
    ,EBCITY
    ,EBSTATE
    ,EBZIP
FROM            
    Select_DriverB
WHERE        
    EquipmentNumber = @BHEQNO
ORDER BY 
    EBEFDTF DESC
```

Comment: Try to have better formatting. Formatting the code as code is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well the parameters are automatically added when you create the datasets. Then, go to the properties for the parameter and change the parameter visibility to hidden or internal.

How are you going to be accessing the report? You can pass the value of the parameter through the url:

[Passing parameter via url to sql server reporting service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078863/passing-parameter-via-url-to-sql-server-reporting-service)