# Hiding menu in SRSS

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have created a few reports which like users to be able to access via url mainly. I want to hide the menu options in these URLs'. Not sure how to do this this. This link:

[remove-top-links-from-report-server](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6c4a0722-b7cc-4a77-9c28-95cb478b743f/remove-top-links-from-report-server)

would require one to modify the actual css file, while this link:
[hiding-tool-bar-from-the-ssrs-report-while-using-them-in-dashboard-crm-2011](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2012/10/20/hiding-tool-bar-from-the-ssrs-report-while-using-them-in-dashboard-crm-2011/)

alludes to appending the url with'&rc:Toolbar=false' which i cannot get to work. So any suggestions or am i left with modifying a css file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try &rv:Toolbar=false instead of &rc:Toolbar=false

This worked for me.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx

Comment: Sorry For the delay. I will check this out and get back to you, although if memory serves i did try this but it did not work.

Comment: Your answer was correct but my url was wrong in general.I used this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078863/passing-parameter-via-url-to-sql-server-reporting-service to correct my url.

Comment: Sorry... I should have posted the full url.

Comment: Absolute life saver, we were utilizing the &rc:Render=true and wondering why the top bar had suddenly gone missing.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the answer from

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6c4a0722-b7cc-4a77-9c28-95cb478b743f/remove-top-links-from-report-server

Please open the Report Manager folder. 
In Reporting Services 2008 (R2), the folder is :\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ ReportManager.

Open the folder “Styles”.

Open the file “ReportingServices.css” using Text Editor such as Notepad.

Change the “table.msrs-topBreadcrumb” to be the following:

**table.msrs-topBreadcrumb { background-color: #EBF3FF; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 84%; font-weight:normal; color:#666666;display:none}**

And this I added myself :

**.toolbarbuttonscell {display: none;}**

Save the file.

Answer (score 1):

One option that might work is to go view the report, go to IE tools->Compatibility view settings, and add the site that the report is viewed at.

Answer (score 1):

Try amending the URL as below (adds 'ReportServer' and calls 'ReportViewer.aspx')

Examples:

https://devreports01/ReportServer_INST01/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?ReportName

https://devreports01/Reports_INST01/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=ReportName

I noticed that the window loaded after deployment did not include the toolbar and this was because of the URL. Seems to be the easiest way to lose the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the link to hide toolbar 
[LINK](https://www.itnota.com/quick-way-to-hide-topbar-ssrs/)

I have implemented by using the below report url

> http://servername:port/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?ReportFolderWithReportName&rs:Command=Render&rc%3aCommand=Render&rc%3aLinkTarget=_blank

Instead of this

> http://servername:port/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=ReportFolderWithReportName&rs:Command=Render&rc%3aCommand=Render&rc%3aLinkTarget=_blank

Answer (score 0):

You can do this configuring the object with c#, setting the "ShowToolBar" option to false. Find the file "you_report.apsx.cs" and modify the "LoadReport" action, like this:

```
private void LoadReport() {
    this.rptViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
    rptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/path_to_you_report.rdlc");
    rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);

    rptViewer.ShowToolBar = false; //This hide the toolbar

    rptViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();}
```

**Update**:rptViewer.ShowToolBar = false does not work with SSRS 2016 
try instead rptViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = false; it Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For mobile reports add this as a query string parameter

```
rs:embed=true
```