# Send current state of Kendo Grid to SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am setting up a couple grids with sorting, grouping and filtering options.  Once the grid is in the state the user wants, I want to use a 'Print Grid' button to send the state to ssrs 2008, to basically make a printable version of the grid.  I have found how to get the state (http://jsbin.com/erefug/1/edit) but I can not find how to send it to ssrs.

I have done just a standard url to a report plenty of times, and I am thinking I somehow need to get the state info into the url, but I am at a loss on how to do that, or if it is event he way to go.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: when you click `Print Grid` button what kind of state you want to send to ssrs.

Comment: @teahou Do you mean passing state as a parameter to SSRS? If so, you can use **ReportViewer.aspx** not Report.aspx to accomplish your task. 
Link 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078863/passing-parameter-via-url-to-sql-server-reporting-service
 Link 2: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586(v=sql.100).aspx