# How to call Multi value parameter in ssrs from c#.net

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report developed using SSRS that contain multi value  nparameter. how can call that parameter from c#.net?

[image]

Comment: You could pass the parameter value in the URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078863/passing-parameter-via-url-to-sql-server-reporting-service

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a list object of parameters. There are a few options depending on where you are getting your source from but it all depends on the source. In the end you will need to pass a Comma Separated string to the UserName parameter. You'll need to adjust for datatypes depending on your query (ie users is actually an int not the string displayed in your screen shot).

To get the string (comma separated) try:

```
  List<string> userNames = new List<string>();

  userNames.Add("Ashok");
  userNames.Add("Chandra");

  parameterValues = string.Join(",", userNames.ToArray());

  List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();

  parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("UserName", userNames));
```

Alternatively you could use the ID's of the Users by creating a list of ints.

Comment: hi ShellNinja, i tried the above code but  my problem was not solved.

Comment: And what is the error? Did you change anything about the code? I just posted an edit in the pipe to add () to the .ToArray if you are referring to a syntax error. If you want help you should always add code or errors - it's impossible to guess.