# SSRS Forcing the parameter inside and outside Report Manager

Tags: excel, reporting-services, parameter-passing, ssrs-2008-r2

This has been quite a mind melter for me:

**SCENARIO:** I've got a report in Report Manager that also has a subscription. In the open orders field it has been requested  that if it's clicked on it should drillthrough to the open sales orders report with the specific product class related to those open orders. So I created the report drillthrough action to open the report using the product class parameter. Inside Report Manager, of course, no problem and works as advertised. But the subscription issues an excel spreadsheet that when you click on the same open orders field it gives a 404 error.

So I spend some time researching, and decide to switch the action to perform a drillthrough to the URL, as I at least can get the open sales orders report to appear with the default parameters(if I just point to the report itself). How do I code in the parameter to pull in the product class parameter from the spreadsheet?  I've tried many variants of the following URL, but nothing has worked so far and it can't be hard-coded as there are many product classes to choose from...

`http://myreportyplace:5765/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fSales%2fOpen+Sales+Orders&ProductClass=Fields!product_Class.value`

I know it's the `Fields!product_Class.value` that's the problem...do I have to force it to look to the cells in excel and would that still work within Report Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after continued searching I found the answer here: [Passing parameter via url to sql server reporting service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078863/passing-parameter-via-url-to-sql-server-reporting-service)

It turns out the answer @snyderj gave solved it for me to replace the `Reports/Pages/Report.aspx` with `ReportServer?/Sales/Open Sales Orders` and including the value after quoting all that out (thanks @Hannover Fist). So the final answer for me to get it to work was:
`="http://myreportyplace/ReportServer?/Sales/Open Sales Orders&ProductClass=" &Fields!product_Class.value`

Answer (score 1):

For your expression, you'll want the link as text and add ( & ) the field to the string.

```
="http://myreportyplace:5765/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fSales%2fOpen+Sales+Orders&ProductClass=" & Fields!product_Class.value
```

Comment: This is true, but the solution has been found in another SO question. +1 for the helps!