# SSRS linking three reports based on the value in one textbox

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting

I have a report named WorkbookInfoReports. There is one field/texbox in this report named **Execution Type**. When report is run, this field shows either **"SSRSEXport**" or **" Fileexport"** based on the parameter. So my task is to link this **Execution Type field** to two other reports based on the value that is showing. For example if this field shows "SSRSExports" value, then I link it to **SSRSInfoReport (in the same solution)**, or if this field shows the value of **"FileExport"** I need to link it to the **" ExportsInfoReport** (in the same solution). How do I link a texbox in one report to two other reports based on the value in that box.

I tries this, but it works only partially.

=SWITCH(Fields!Type.Value="SSRSExport","SSRSInfoReport",Fields!Type.Value="FileExport","ExportsInfoReport")

Whatelse can I do? Thank you How do I incorporate parameters for those other two reports into my expression?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the textbox a link, you can specify a URL in the Action section of the properties.

[image]

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078863/passing-parameter-via-url-to-sql-server-reporting-service) on how to add the parameter value to the URL.