# Passing a MDX Parameter to an URL in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a (very simple) report that load yearly data from an SSAS Cube for any given customer number. The report is linked in our CRM and I want to load the report within the CRM by passing the customer number into the URL.

I know how to do it with a relational dataset, but I'm at a loss here.

I thought the URL was:

http://reportserver/CRM/Salesreport&Customer=[customer].[fields!id.value]="1234"

Where 1234 is being passed on by the CRM.

Edit: This is for SSAS-datasets, not relational datasets!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameter via url to sql server reporting service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078863/passing-parameter-via-url-to-sql-server-reporting-service)

Answer (score 0):

When working with MDX, you have to be mindful of the syntax of the parameter values. The value of "1234" doesn't exist in your SSAS cube. There are several ways to go about applying parameters and filters, but I'll give you one example.

1. Change the URL to be in this format: 
   http://reportserver/CRM/Salesreport&Customer=1234
2. Add a Filter to your dataset where Fields!id.Value = Parameters!Customer.Value

By using a dataset filter, you are avoiding the complications of MDX syntax and using the data after the query has been run. A more efficient approach would be to convert the parameter to MDX syntax and pass it into the query, but that requires more work.

Also, if you check the Parameter box while in the Query Designer, it will automatically add a parameter along with a hidden dataset to populate it. That can be very useful because it converts the values into MDX syntax for you.