# SSRS Query Execution failed for dataset rsErrorExecutingCommand

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am sorry if this is a duplicate question. I have been searching for two days for an answer to this.

I have an SSRS report that has been deployed to a SQL 2008R2 Reporting server. I have developed it using VS2015. When I hit my report server **(sql4/reportingserver_sql4)** OR in VS 2015 I can run the report by manually entering a parameter and the report returns the correct data and displays the report.

I am trying to pass the parameter via URL and it looks like this

```
http://[some foo url]/PrintRpt.aspx?IrrNumber=5109
```

The 5109 is the data for parameter IrrNumber.

But when I try this I get the following error:

> An error has occurred during report processing. **(rsProcessingAborted)**
>   Query execution failed for dataset 'sp_IrrRptData_ds'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
>   For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

This is trying to call a stored procedure.

*Report Error Message:*

[image]

I do not understand why this is crashing. Can anyone shed some light?

If any other code is needed please let me know.

Comment: i understand the need to be able to read the post but it seems like nit picking instead of answering the problem.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078863/passing-parameter-via-url-to-sql-server-reporting-service

Comment: Have you enabled Remote Errors yet?

Comment: It looks as if your parameters either aren't being passed correctly or your sproc simply can't handle them.  Go look at your SSRS execution log for the error message that will be recorded there.

Comment: I am sorry for the late response. Necoras, yes i did do that and it lead me to the problem. Which I am sorry to say turned out to be my fat fingers. I had an extra colon in the http address. Thanks to eveyone who helped me.