# Tableau report with SSRS link

Tags: reporting-services, tableau-api

I have created a dashboard with aggregated numbers.For raw data I want to use an image with embedded URL to an SSRS report. My tableau dashboard has 8-9 filters. I want that when a filter is selected in the dashboard, same filters should apply to the SSRS report.I am able to open the report but unable to retain the filters.

Comment: Haven't worked with tableau but when you call the report are you calling the url? If so can't you insert the params into the URL?

Comment: There are many questions already on how to pass parameters in the URL. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/120613 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/1078863/2033717