# Hide SSRS Toolbar

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to hide the entire toolbar in an SSRS report URL.  I keep reading that this is possible by passing the parameter rc:Toolbar=false but I am unable to get it to work.  We are on SSRS 2012 and are not using sharepoint.

The report I am trying to set this up for is for a Dashboard report at the url below.

http:///Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=/Enterprise Systems/Roadside/Dashboard

What am I doing wrong?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835(v=sql.105).aspx

[Passing parameter via url to sql server reporting service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078863/passing-parameter-via-url-to-sql-server-reporting-service)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to access this via the 'ReportServer' path, not 'Reports' so in your case it would be something like this..

```
http://mySSRSServerName/reportserver?/Enterprise Systems/Roadside/Dashboard&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0&rc:Toolbar=false
```