# In SSRS 2008, how do pass variables from one report to another?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

How do I, pass a variable from one to another report when I launch a report through the Action Property of an Object?  And how do I use the received string variable as the contents of a dataset or at least the contents of a defined variable in a dataset.  Also, how would I be able to use that variable as text in a text box?  Finally, how would I pass multiple variables?

Comment: You just search for it in your favourite search engine and read one of the hundreds of articles, like this one.
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/drillthrough-reports-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017
It basically the same in all version of SSRS

Comment: xarzu is the issue solved

Answer (score 1):

## Passing parameters via URL

If you are working with Report parameters, you can pass parameters to a report via URL, as example:

```
https://myrshost/ReportServer?/AdventureWorks 2008R2/Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2&ReportMonth=3&ReportYear=2008
```

**Reference**

- [Pass a Report Parameter Within a URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pass-a-report-parameter-within-a-url?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Passing parameter via url to sql server reporting service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078863/passing-parameter-via-url-to-sql-server-reporting-service)

---

## Drillthrough Reports

If you want to navigate from one report to another one, by clicking on an item or information that would be sent as parameter to another one. Then you should read about **Drillthrough Reports**.

- [Drillthrough Reports (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/drillthrough-reports-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Tutorial: Creating Drillthrough and Main Reports (Report Builder)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tutorial-creating-drillthrough-and-main-reports-report-builder?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Drill Through Report or Hyperlink to other SSRS Report Passing Values from one Report to Another in SSRS](http://msbionlineanand.blogspot.com/2014/12/lesson-19-ssrs-drill-through-report.html)
- [Drill Through Reports in SSRS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/drill-through-reports-in-ssrs/)