# Rendering SSRS Report into Excel URL

Tags: reporting-services, report, render

I tried to render the SSRS report into excel .csv file. using URL

```
&rs:command=render&rs:format=csv
```

while the page just refreshed and did not do any work.

I only have IE as the browser in the server and not sure whether this could be the issue.

Please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: It *should* work. Does the report have parameters? Does it render correctly on the page when you don't use the format command? I get the Open/Save dialog box at the bottom when I use the format in the address bar.

Comment: can you post the full URL that you tried, it might be that you are using the web portal address instead of the reportserver address

Comment: That is what i have :  http://testserver/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fILS%2fTest+Reports%2fTest+Number+List&rs:command=render&rs:format=csv

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party but as someone who has recently struggled with this (excessively in my opinion!), I found the answer with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078863/passing-parameter-via-url-to-sql-server-reporting-service/16968693#16968693?newreg=0c4694de7c6d47d58d0427ecb62e2100); specifically snyderj's answer.

This bit in particular:

**If applicable, be sure to replace Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath= with ReportServer?. In other words: Instead of this:**

```
http://server/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=/ReportFolder/ReportSubfolder/ReportName
```

**Use this syntax:**

```
http://server/ReportServer?/ReportFolder/ReportSubfolder/ReportName
```

The key point being ReportServer?. Don't be like me and assume you're supposed to replace that text with the name of your report server. Copy ReportServer? and drop that bad boy directly into your link.

So, for your example this link *should* work

```
http://testserver/ReportServer?/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fILS%2fTest+Reports%2fTest+Number+List&rs:command=render&rs:format=csv
```

Do remember the folders too if you have them. You'll notice they're included in snyderj's example.

One thing I did notice when implementing this, once you follow the link it changes. I had my original link of:

```
https://server/reports/report/folder/ReportName
```

which I changed to:

```
https://server/ReportServer?/folder/ReportName&rc:Zoom=Page Width
```

Well, when followed it changes to:

```
https://server/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/folder/ReportName&rc:Zoom=Page%20Width
```

The changed version appears to work just as well for use elsewhere such as embedding into a report. I'm not sure if that change is specific to my system (still learning!) but just a heads up.