# Passing a parameter via URL to SQL Server Reporting Services when a parameter value contains special character &

Tags: reporting-services

I know we have a similar question here

[Passing a parameter via URL to SQL Server Reporting Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078863/passing-a-parameter-via-url-to-sql-server-reporting-services)

My issue is if I have a parameter that contains the special character &, how can I pass it via URL?
In the following example (borrowed from the link above), if my UserID parameter has a value of "abc123", I will have the following syntax

```
http://server.domain.com/ReportServer?/ReportFolder1/ReportSubfolder1/ReportName&UserID=ABC123&rc:Toolbar=false
```

But the problem is if I have UserID = "abc&123", with the "&" as a special character, if I still use the previous format, it will fail out

```
http://server.domain.com/ReportServer?/ReportFolder1/ReportSubfolder1/ReportName&UserID=ABC&123&rc:Toolbar=false
```

So how should I handle this "&" in "abc&123" ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your time.

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 'think' you'll need to encode the & to '%26'

```
http://server.domain.com/ReportServer?/ReportFolder1/ReportSubfolder1/ReportName&UserID=ABC%26123&rc:Toolbar=false
```

Comment: Thanks Alan for your help, but unfortunately, it does not work. I tried various other ways as well, such as \& or `&

Comment: Thanks Alan!, Your suggestion actually works, the only thing I need to do in my powershell script which uses invoke-WebRequest, I need to add -UseBasicParsing, and then together with your solution, everything works like a magic. Thanks again Alan, really appreciate it.