# Button in parameter to click to previous week in Reportbuilder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using Microsoft SQL Report Builder 2012 3.0 to make myself a weekly report. Now I have a StartDate (monday from the previous week) and an EndDate (previous sunday) as parameters. Is there a way to put some sort of button next to these parameters that will let me go a week further back.

Let's say my StartDate will be the 12th of May and my EndDate is the 18th of May. By clicking this button my start date would go to the 5th of May and my end date to the 11th of May.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. You cannot add a button to the parameter pane.

Obvious answer: There is a button next to `DateTime` datatype parameters that show a calendar, which allow you to easily choose a date. But, I am certain you are aware of this.

Possible solution: Add a link in the report itself that, when clicked, will rerun the report with the date parameters you desire. The URL parameters for the dates would be dynamic, and based on the parameter values of the report currently being viewed. This way, you could have both a back URL and a forward URL, depending on whether it is applicable or not.

This might help you: [How to do Jump to URL in SSRS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009548/how-to-do-jump-to-url-in-ssrs)

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely try your possible solution!

Answer (score 0):

How about adding buttons to the report itself?

1. Draw text boxes like buttons for "Previous Month" and "Next Month"
2. Define Actions to manipulate the value of the parameter(s)

[image: Buttons are Text Boxes]

[image: Text Box Properties...Action]

[image: Setting BusinessMonth Parameter]